# Compiling Smart Contract in Java

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, java, web3j

I want to compile a smart contract (solidity code) in Java. Currently I am using the web3j library. When I run the method `web3j.ethCompileSolidity(contract)` I'm getting the following error: `The method eth_compileSolidity does not exist/is not available`

I created the following code to compile a smart contract at runtime:

```
EthCompileSolidity ethCompileSolidity = web3j.ethCompileSolidity(contract).send();
Map<String, EthCompileSolidity.Code> compiledSolidity = ethCompileSolidity.getCompiledSolidity();
```

The method `web3j.ethGetCompilers()` doesn't work either. It's returning the following error: `The method eth_compileSolidity does not exist/is not available`

On [Github](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/209) I read something about deprecated eth_compile methods.

Is there still a way to compile smart contracts in Java using this library?

Comment: Probably the smart move is to ship the compiler `solc` with your application and then shell to it to compile. Another alternative (if you support node/javascript) to ship the javascript package `solc`, but it is less performant.

Comment: @Ismael any idea of how to ship solc with my java app?

Comment: @forhas It is better if you ask a new question about that.

Answer (score 2):

You are right is's because of deprecated eth_compile

There is no easy way to solve it. You can:

- downgrade geth version on your dev machine
- create a custom version of geth with a diff and keep it in your branch

Answer (score 0):

I got it by running solc executable from my java code (I'm running windows os).
I downloaded solc.exe from https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases, put it in my classpath and used the following code:

```
List<String> commandParts = Lists.newArrayList("path.to.solc.exe", "--bin", "path.to.sol.file");
//loading solc.exe file
InputStream fileURL = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(pathToFile)
solcFile = File.createTempFile("solc", "exe");
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(fileURL, solcFile); // FileUtils of org.apache.commons.io
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commandParts)
        .directory(executable.getParentFile());
processBuilder.environment().put("LD_LIBRARY_PATH",
        executable.getParentFile().getCanonicalPath());

Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

Remember to close your stream (`fileURL`), compilation output is taken from `process.getInputStream()`, if compilation fails errors are taken from `process.getErrorStream()`

Comment: I am unable to understand the few contexts of the code, Could you publish the complete code with explanation?